# How to print 1 to x in a column where x is determined by a cell value?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to print 1 to `x` in column A where `x = integer in cell B3`. In the screenshot above, the integer in cell `B3` is 9, so the formula will print 1 to 9 in column A. Is there any way/formula can achieve this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you wanting the numbers ```1```  to ```9```  to turn green according to the value in ```B3```? Or do you want the numbers that appear in ```Column A```  to appear in sequence depending on the number in ```B3```?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, `SEQUENCE` is the answer that I'm looking for:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `sequence` function as following, the list of sequence number will be auto-populated, try play around with the optional argument `SEQUENCE(rows, [columns], [start], [step])`, you may discover more things you need:

```
=SEQUENCE(B27)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Kin Siang! I never know there is a formula `Sequence` :)

Comment: Welcome, I also discover it recently :)